# 5.1 Surround sound will not keep its configuration

Tags: ubuntu, alsa, pulse-audio, spdif

in `pavucontrol` I have my output set to `Digital Surround 5.1(IEC958/AC3)`

When I open a video with `VLC` (my preferred option) OR `GNOME Media player` I hear no sound.

VLC is configured to use `pulseaudio` as the audio device.

I have noticed that if I go to the `System Settings/Sound/test sound` dialog, sometimes I hear a female voice saying 'Front left', 'Front right' etc, sometimes a 'bloop' noise from each speaker.  Either way it causes VLC audio to kick into life on all 6 speakers.

If I then then skip a chapter, skip forward, or restart `VLC` I am back where I started - no sound.

Could someone explain for me what is happening, and also how I might configure my system reliably to output 5.1 Surround sound to its optical cable?

Diagnostics can be found [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0ed9106630a0cfa44283e9ab0869803dc8012fac)

Comment: There are many sound trouble-shooters you could try : [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), or [Resolve no sound problem](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/), or [Nvidia hdmi audio](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1668737) (if it applies). Try them and let us know.

Comment: What version of  pulseaudio do you  have?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483555/problem-with-5-1-ac-3-through-alsa-pulseaudio-on-spdif-ubuntu-14-04) post gave me the answer I needed, though it did not explain quite what was wrong